# Mule esb 3.8 How to check if property exist in payload and validate it is guid (uuid)

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I know how to validate property if its match regexp:

> regex = "^[{]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[}]?$"

for guid, but if its not send in payload - receiving error, is it a simple way to check if property exist and do validate only then?
As per now I check with choice if its exist and if so then do validation, but interested if its more smarter way to do such as if I will have 20 properties to check its becomes very messy flow.

For example 3 validations at the moment:
[image]

Comment: Please share an example of you current validation. Do lo properties have the same validation?

Comment: they all different, and depending on the flow can be completely different at all, only type of validation by regexp is same but patterns are different.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for code or errors. Use the text XML representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Validations Module [All validator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/validations-module#validating-many-conditions-at-once) which seems to cover this use case. Note that you can not customize the exception or message. If this is not acceptable then you could use individual validations in the flow instead.

Example:

```xml
  <validation:all doc:name="Validation">
    <validation:validations>
      <validation:is-not-empty doc:name="Validation" value="#[payload.firstName]" message="Firstname cannot be empty"/>
      <validation:is-not-empty doc:name="Validation" value="#[payload.lastName]" message="Lastname cannot be empty"/>
      <validation:is-number message="Not an adult" value="#[payload.age]" minValue="18" numberType="INTEGER"/>
      <validation:is-email email="#[payload.email]" />
      <validation:matches-regex message="Invalid SSN" value="#[payload.ssn]" regex="^(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}-(?!00)[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$"/>
      <validation:validate-size value="#[payload.ssn]" min="11" max="11" message="SSN too short"/>
    </validation:validations>
  </validation:all>
```

Comment: oh, so if I got this right, if attribute exist, it will jump to next one and then able to verify it match regexp. By conditions I need return back why its not pass validation and would like to avoid coding custom validator, but this still better as I can avoid unnecessary choices

Comment: I don't think the intention of the operation is to validate attribute existence but if it doesn't exists it will fail the validation. You could also check attributes exists using a DataWeave script first.

Comment: Already tested, works as a charm, also its possible to do separate message per each via customisation so its absolutely that I need to :)